# When did the first organ transplant operation occur?

Tags: medicine

Is it in 800 AD or 1800 AD. Was it done in Rome? Was it done in India?
What was the name of the surgeon?

Comment: Do you mean human transplants or any type? Also, are you looking for only successful ones? Also, are you talking about internal organs, or would skin transplants count?

Comment: in human ,successful operation and any part of the body,skin or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pre-19th century transplants are not well documented. The first possibly real human transplant was in India. It is unknown if it was successful or not:

> The first reasonable account is of the Indian surgeon Sushruta in the 2nd century BC, who used autografted skin transplantation in nose reconstruction rhinoplasty. Success or failure of these procedures is not well documented. [*-Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_transplantation)

The first transplants known to be successful occurred in the 16th century:

> Centuries later, the Italian surgeon Gasparo Tagliacozzi [1546 – 1599] performed successful skin autografts.

However, those were transplants from one part of the body to another in the same individual

The first between two individuals was in the 20th century:

In 1905, Eduard Zirm conducted the [first successful transplant](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16402960?dopt=Abstract) between two individuals. He transplanted the corneas of an 11-year-old boy into a Czech day laborer. That was the first successful human transplant between two individuals that has been verified.

Comment: Note that until the late 1800's, the importance of hand-washing to prevent infections was not widely accepted. Trying to perform a transplant of an internal organ before then would have resulted in so many secondary infections that I can't see it ever having much hope of saving the patient.

Comment: True, but that wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: ...which is why I didn't make it an answer. However, I think it backs up the timing you gave here, so I thought it might be helpful.